# Possible to authenticate facebook from unix console?

Tags: facebook, unix, console

I'm playing around with an embedded device, running a linux kernel.  It has web access via a proxy.  My question is, is it possible to login via the unix console?

I can retrieve the login page using `wget http://m.facebook.com`, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this project before:

http://sachachua.com/blog/2008/08/sweet-facebook-in-emacs/

Pretty cool if you're one of those types who need to do *everything* in Emacs...

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't quite right for my application. The link essentially uses an emacs based browser to authenticate.  Not quite what I'm after.